# View statisctics on WSO2 API manager Analitytcs

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I've deployed wso2 api manager version 3.2.0 on k8s with keycloak as identity manager , i'm not able to view stats on Analitycs Dashboard for APIs published by developers .

How to manage Analytics permissions to have admin access on it.

Comment: Have you followed https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/ to setup APIM analytics in the environment?

Comment: In Analytics also, it connects with the users in APIM. Please refer - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/managing-users-and-roles/managing-user-roles/

You can find some configs in here as reference - https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/master/docker-compose/apim-is-as-km-with-analytics